# Answering a question that you voted to close

Tags: discussion, answers, vote-to-close

When is appropriate for a user that voted to close a question to go ahead and answer the question as well?

Granted that if their closed opinion wasn't accepted by the community, they shouldn't hesitated to answer it, but what about if it is in the middle of active voting with a good chance of being closed? Is it appropriate to vote one minute to close it and then answer it the next?

I'm assuming no edits of the question in the interim, of course.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't seem quite right to me. If they vote to close, it's either because they consider it off topic, or unclear. If it's unclear, they shouldn't answer (or vice versa - if it's answerable, it's not unclear). If it's off topic, it doesn't seem right to answer.

If someone wants to help despite being off topic, some at SE (specifically SO) would discourage it, but in any case, should be done as a comment.

Answering and voting to close at a later date is very different though.