# Upvoting answers on a question that should be closed

Tags: discussion

Should one refrain from upvoting answers on a question that he/she believes should be closed (e.g. duplicate or off topic)?

This is similar to [this question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3320/answering-a-question-that-you-voted-to-close) but there is not necessarily a reason why the answer should be the same.

Comment: Duplicate could be very different from the other close reasons in this regard

Comment: @DoubleAA Good point. For the record, the question that prompted me to ask this was closed as off topic. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88322/the-jewish-q-e-d